# Problem with instaling

Tags: system-installation

I have a problem, and I need help. I have HP pavilion Laptop with i7 11Gn processor. When I begin installing ubuntu I can't select my SSD disk?
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the screen when you cannot select your SSD? Can you access your SSD from a live session of Ubuntu? Also, which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1348330/edit) your question

Comment: I can't access my SSD when im select try ubuntu

Comment: I see my flash drive only

Comment: And sorry for my English, im havent enought practice )

Comment: (Your English is understandable, please don't worry about that). By any chance do you have secure boot enabled, and is Windows installed there? If so, try disabling secure boot. Also, is that 30 GB NTFS partition your flash drive?

Comment: Secure boot is disabled, and yes 30 GB is my flash drive )

Comment: Open a live Ubuntu session (try Ubuntu), and check if the SSD is detected in `Try Ubuntu`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126909/discussion-between---and-archisman-panigrahi).

Answer (score 0):

If you are dual booting with Windows

1. Boot into Windows and goto the settings and disable "Fast Startup". Exit Windows.
2. Then boot into the UEFI/BIOS and as indicated above, make sure you are in UEFI mode and Secure Boot is disabled.

You should then be able to boot into your live session and see your SSD.

Please let us know if this works.

Edit: Since you only want Ubuntu and not Windows, go into your BIOS/UEFI and switch your disk setting in the BIOS from **RAID** to **AHCI**.

Comment: I installed windows just for updating my bios, couse my bios haven't function update from the flash, secure boot is disabled, and  IPv4+IPv6 (UEFI) active

Comment: And I can't change RST on ACHI in my bios, bios is the latest version

Comment: There was the same problem with windows, but it was easier to solve, since there you just needed to load the so-called driver and write to a USB flash drive, initially windows also did not detect my SSD disk

Comment: i7 11GN processors )))

Comment: And I need just Ubuntu.

Comment: @АрсенийБудаев When you boot into a live session, run GParted and refer to [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) to format the drive correctly, as if it is an unformatted drive. It is possible that your drive isn't formatted correctly.

Comment: I checked this tutorial, in the live session I was open my terminal and write the command sudo lshw -c disk and detect my flash drive only, but in BIOS i detect my SSD disk.

Comment: Type `sudo lshw -c disk` Also include a picture of your BIOS showing the SSD

Comment: Are you mean upload those pictures?

Comment: @АрсенийБудаев Yes,  the more information we have the better, but please also try the edit I made to my answer

Comment: Hey! I'm sorry that I haven't been in touch for so long, since I was on vacation. As a result, I gave that laptop) In fact, it seems to me that in this situation some kind of driver is needed, but I don't know which one)